# Why would AsSequential() be needed to preserve order before Take()?

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, plinq

[From MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460680%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> The following example shows one scenario in which
>   AsSequential is required, namely to preserve the ordering
>   that was established in a previous clause of the query.
>
> ```
>     // Paste into PLINQDataSample class.
>     static void SequentialDemo()
>     {
>         var orders = GetOrders();
>         var query = (from ord in orders.AsParallel()
>                      orderby ord.CustomerID
>                      select new
>                      {
>                          Details = ord.OrderID,
>                          Date = ord.OrderDate,
>                          Shipped = ord.ShippedDate
>                      }).
>                             AsSequential().Take(5);
>     }
> ```

I've set up the `PLINQDataSample` class, and I've been running this `SequentialDemo()`, but no matter what I do I can't find a situation where removing `AsSequential()` makes any difference.

Can anyone shed some light on this? I understand that `AsSequential()` is used for complex queries where some parts should be run sequentially and some in parallel. I've seen multiple sources use this as an example, saying `AsSequential()` needs to be used before `Take()` in order to preserve order. But order seems to be preserved without it.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460677(v=vs.110).aspx)?  It sheds a lot of light on switching order preservation on and off, including answering your exact question.

Comment: That page doesn't mention `AsSequential()`.

Comment: It performs the same function, except it additionally instructs LINQ to to stop executing in parallel, and return to single threaded mode.

Comment: Why would that be needed to preserve order?

Comment: Because PLINQ executes batches in multiple threads that may complete in an undefined order.  If you want to take the top 5 items, you want to make sure you really have the top five of the complete set, not just the top five of the first batch that completed.

Comment: Does `orderby` not take care of that?

Comment: Apparently not.

Comment: OrderBy requires the entire query to complete before yielding values.